# If not working after lower-casing and trimming

Tags: javascript, html

I've made a website with a decrypting function and an experiment, at the experiment you have an input and it checks for some codes, I've wanted to make that easier and so I've added a *.toString().toLowerCase().trim* but when I now want to check if there's match it just says the *var* (so the first *if*) 
Here's the JS code:

```
function Codes() {
  var DeInf = "No Public Developer Info yet."
  var Error = "By the time you've read this the page has closed itself already"
  var index = '<a href="index.html">Get to the Index!</a>'
  var Errore = "No recognised Code!"

  var B2 = document.getElementById("CodeInput").value;
  var A1 = B2.toString().toLowerCase().trim;

  if (A1 === 'devinfo'||'developerinfo') {
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = DeInf;
    }
else if (A1 === 'error'){
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = Error;
    close();
    }
else if (A1 === 'newtons pendulum'||'newton'||'pendulum') {
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = Newton;
    }
else if (A1 === 'binary') {
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "11111100001";
    }
else if (A1 === 'index') {
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = index;
    }
    else if (A1 === 'randomnumber') {
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);
    }
else {
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = Errore;
    }
}
```

The HTML:

```
<input id="CodeInput"  placeholder="Code" class="Input2"><br />
<button onClick="Codes();" id="Check" class="Exp-Button" >Check</button>
```

I've tried searching if others had a similar problem and have failed to find anything, I've also tried to split the variable into 4

```
var A4 = document.getElementById("CodeInput").value;
var A3 = A4.toString();
var A2 = A3.toLowerCase();
var A1 = A2.trim;
```

Comment: `B2.toString().toLowerCase().trim()`.

Comment: Debug! Trace through with a debugger examining variables as you go. And/or add print statements to examine the variable values during execution.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem but  your `or` statements are wrong. They will not return what you expect. For example you should do `if( A1 === 'devinfo' || A1 === 'developerinfo' ) {`

Comment: CFreak, they work, before not trimming etc, they worked as well

Comment: @Dia.Frost They weren't working, they were all truthy.

Comment: @BenM They did, I have one that shows the time I have _if (A1 === 'date'||'time') {_ amongst all the others and I was able to use all codes including date and time (both showed the same thing of course)

Comment: @Dia.Frost No, trust me, they weren't: https://jsfiddle.net/zntdeo9q/

Comment: @Dia.Frost Arguing with those who are trying to help you will not help.

Comment: @BenM well I've realized what my mistake was at that time, only Date and time were written like that (A1 === 'Date||'Time') so they would be the ones that evaluated to true...

Comment: Yes, but now the same is also true of several of your `if` blocks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot that `trim` is a method, not a property:

`.trim` should be `.trim()`

Also, there's no need to call `.toString()` on `B2` because `B2` is the value of a DOM element and DOM element values are always strings.

Additionally, scanning the document for an element has a performance cost, so if you are going to need an element reference more than once, cache the result of the first scan and use the cached version for the others.

`.innerHTML` is for assigning a string that contains HTML that should be parsed. If you are setting content on an element and that content doesn't include HTML, use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` as this will save the performance cost of parsing the string for HTML that doesn't exist.

You are referring to a variable called `Newton`, but I don't see that declared anywhere. Is it declared at a higher scope in code that you aren't showing here?

Lastly, since you are checking the same thing (`A1`) for many possible values, a **[`switch` expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)** would be better than an `if/then` in terms of readability and performance. Related to that is your attempt at logical OR (`||`), which needs a complete expression on both sides of the operator. You have:

```
if (A1 === 'devinfo'||'developerinfo')
```

As long as `developerinfo` is not a "falsey" value (`0`, `undefined`, `false`, `null` or an empty string), it will always be converted to `true`, so even when `A1` is not equal to either `devinfo` or `developerinfo`, code execution will fall into that true branch. The code would be:

```
if (A1 === 'devinfo'|| A1 === 'developerinfo')
```

Your code can be re-written as:

```
function Codes() {
  var DeInf = "No Public Developer Info yet.";
  var Error = "By the time you've read this the page has closed itself already";
  var idx = '<a href="index.html">Get to the Index!</a>';
  var Errore = "No recognised Code!";   
  var B2 = document.getElementById("CodeInput").value;
  var A1 = B2.toLowerCase().trim();
  var info = document.getElementById("info");

  switch (A1) {
    case 'devinfo':
      // Fall-through intended
    case 'developerinfo':
      info.textContent = DeInf;
      break;
    case 'error':
      info.textContent = Error;
      close();
      break;
    case 'newtons pendulum':
      // Fall-through intended
    case 'newton':
      // Fall-through intended
    case 'pendulum':
      info.textContent = Newton;
      break;
    case 'binary':
      info.innerHTML = "11111100001";
      break;
    case 'index':
      info.innerHTML = idx;
      break;
    case 'randomnumber':
      info = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);
      break;
    default:
      info.textContent = Errore;
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I've just tried that and it still doesn't want to work....

Comment: Then, you have additional issues. What does your console say?

Comment: Now its a problem with the button not actually calling the function, but there are plenty of solutions for that out there...

Answer (score -2):

```
var A1 = B2.toString().toLowerCase().replace(/^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g, '');
```

There has some `if`  conditions which is not correct. use like this,

```
if (A1 === 'devinfo' || A1 === 'developerinfo')
```

Comment: No, but `trim()` *is* a method of string. Why is using `replace()` preferable over `trim()` here?

Comment: Sure `trim` is a property of string.

Comment: My fault. I was trying to support to all browsers. (below IE9)

Comment: Why? Less than 1% of users use IE 8. Unless you have a proprietary business app. to support, no one cares about IE 8.